# sugarcrm REST update Relationship beteen Contacts and Accounts javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, sugarcrm

I have following code:

```js
$.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v2/rest.php', {

            method: "set_relationship",
            input_type: "JSON",
            response_type: "JSON",
            rest_data: '{"session":"' + SugarSessionId + '","module_name":"Contacts","module_id":"' + CurrentContactId + '","link_field_name":"accounts","related_ids":["'+ CurrentAccountId +'"]}'
        }, function(data) {
            if (data !== undefined) {
                var addAccountResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

The relationship between Contacts and Companies working quite well. I would now like to assign a new company to the contact. I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As relationship between contacts and accounts is defined as a many-to-many and not a one-to-many if you want only one link between one contact and an account you should in first step delete the current relation and after adding your new relation

Something like that:

```
// Delete previous relation
$.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v2/rest.php', {
    method: "set_relationship",
    input_type: "JSON",
    response_type: "JSON",
    rest_data: '{"session":"' + SugarSessionId + '","module_name":"Contacts","module_id":"' + CurrentContactId + '","link_field_name":"accounts","related_ids":["'+ OldAccountId +'"],"name_value_list":[],"deleted":"1"}'
    }, function(data) {
    if (data !== undefined) {
        var addAccountResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});

// Add previous relation
$.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v2/rest.php', {
    method: "set_relationship",
    input_type: "JSON",
    response_type: "JSON",
    rest_data: '{"session":"' + SugarSessionId + '","module_name":"Contacts","module_id":"' + CurrentContactId + '","link_field_name":"accounts","related_ids":["'+ NeAccountId +'"],"name_value_list":[],"deleted":"1"}'
    }, function(data) {
    if (data !== undefined) {
        var addAccountResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean "delete": "0" in / / add previous relation. And another question: how do I get ["'+ OldAccountId +'"] ?

Comment: Yes in add part it's a deleted:0. For the OldAccountId that represents the currant account_id field in your contact entry before your modification

Comment: Thank you that works. Actually CurrentAccountId is the NewAccountId

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
$.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v2/rest.php', {
        method: "set_relationship",
        input_type: "JSON",
        response_type: "JSON",
        rest_data: '{"session":"' + SugarSessionId + '","module_name":"Accounts","module_id":"' + CurrentAccountId + '","link_field_name":"contacts","related_ids":["'+ CurrentContactId +'"]}'
    }, function(data) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            var addAccountResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
}
```

});

Comment: This works well for creating but not for update. I get two entries in the contacts list, an entry with the old values ​​and with the new values. In the database there are two entries.